# Calculating hyperbolic distance on the hyperboloid $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=-10000$

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I want to calculate the hyperbolic distance on a hyperbolid defined by $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=-10000$.

From wikipedia and other sources I got the formula that the distance for two points   $x$ and $y$ on the hyperboloid the distance is 
$$d(x,y) = \operatorname{arccosh}(\;\lvert (x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_3y_3)\rvert\;) \tag{1}$$

If I take, for example, two points on the $xz$ plane, like 
$$x=(0,0,100) \quad\text{and}\quad y=(50,0,111.803)$$ 
the distance can also be calculated by the length of the curve $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+10000}$, which is 
$$\int_0^{100}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2}} = 50.0557 \tag{2}$$

If I try to calculate the distance with the formula above I get $$d(x,y)=\operatorname{arccosh}(\;\lvert 100\cdot 111.803\;\rvert) = 10.015 \tag{3}$$

The formula above might be only valid on the unit hyperboloid. Therefore I tried to normalize the hyperboloid. In my case: 
$$0.0001\cdot x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=-1 \tag{4}$$

But 
$$d(x,y)=\operatorname{arccosh}\left(\;0.0001\cdot \lvert 100\cdot 111.803 \rvert\;\right) = 0.4812 \tag{5}$$
which is even if I scale it back somehow far away from $50.0557$.

> Can someone see my mistake?

Comment: Is the metric given in your first formula equivalent to the Euclidean arc length?

Comment: I am not quite sure from where the first formula comes from. But if you look at the hyperboloid in a 3D cartesian coordinate system the arc length of a line on the hyperboloid is equivalent to the eculidean arc length. But to find a parametrization of a line on the hyperboloid and solve its integral gets difficult if it's not for this easy case where $x_2 =0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyperbolic distance on the hyperboloid model $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=-1$ is obtained by the metric
$$
ds^2=dx_1^2+dx_2^2\color{red}{-}dx_3^2
$$
so the hyperbolic distance between your two points is
$$
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{100}}\int_0^{\color{red}{50}}\sqrt{1\color{red}{-}f'(x_1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x_1
$$
giving the answer
$$
\sinh^{-1}\frac12\approx 0.4812
$$

Comment: Does the hyperbolic distance vary depending on metric / model we choose ... Poincare3D , Klein .. hyperboloid model etc.. ?

Comment: They are isometric with each other.